# Module method access restriction

Tags: ruby

I have class `C` that inherits class `A` and includes module `B`. `A` has a method `baz`.

```
class A
  def baz; 5 end
end

module B
  def foobaz; baz end
end

class C < A
  include B
  def barbaz; baz end
end
```

I want to disallow `B` instance from (indirectly) calling `baz`, but  allow `C` instance to call `baz`.

```
B.new.foobaz # => error
C.new.foobaz # => no error
C.new.barbaz # => no error
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Just declare `A#baz` as `private`.

Comment: `B.new` doesn't work - you can't create instances of a module.

Comment: @Stefan You are right. That was my interpretation. That was the only way to interpret what the OP mentioned. After all, the OP's question probably does not make sense.

Comment: @MikeJackson I tried to simplify and make your point clear. But as Stefan points out, it does not make sense. If you had something different in mind, please edit (based on my edit), and make the question clear. But please don't go back to your original post as that included too many things that are not to the point.

Comment: I suspect that `C.new.foobaz` should raise an error (because `baz` was called from within `B`), whereas `C.new.barbaz` should not (because `baz` was called from within `C`).

Comment: I believe a small user scenario would help corner your requirements. Do you want A = Execution environment, B = Executor, C = SafeEnvironment, and to prevent B from working if not "included" in a safe environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you wanted to do ?

```
class A
  def baz; 5 end
end

module B
  module_function
  def foobaz
    self.respond_to(:baz) ? baz : "No baz defined :("
  end
end

class C < A
  include B
  def barbaz; baz end
end

B.foobaz # => "No baz defined :("
C.new.foobaz # => 5
C.new.barbaz # => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**My option:**

```
class A
  private def baz; 5 end
end

module B
  def foobaz; self.baz end
end

class C < A
  include B
  def barbaz; baz end
end

C.new.foobaz # => private method `baz' called
C.new.barbaz # => no error
```